# I'm missing my core search module

Tags: 7, search

I'm running Drupal 7.12 and had to build a module that extends the search functions of the core Search Module. I made the module, installed it in my custom module folder and reloaded my Drupal site only to find that the search bar couldn't be found on the page...

I looked through the module selector on my dashboard and looked through the core modules. Surprisingly, there was no search module listed in the core module section, although my module did show up in my custom module section (which is irrelevant because the module I wrote needs the core search engine to work).

I checked through my Drupal on my FTP site and found that the files for the core search module are still there.

Why isn't it appearing in my dashboard core module list, and how do I get my Drupal site to recognize that the files are still there?

Answer (score 3):

I'd guess that your custom module is called `search`, which would conflict with the core Search module, also named `search`.

There's no such thing as namespaces with regards to Drupal modules (at least out of the box, I'm not sure if there are any contrib modules that deal with this. My gut instinct is that there wouldn't be). Each module needs to be individually named, or the last module of the same name that Drupal comes across will be the one it uses.

Make sure your module is not called `search`; that includes making sure the folder name for the module, the name of the `.info` file, name of `.module` file, etc. are not called `search.info` etc. That should make sure that both modules are available in your module list.

Comment: Yes, I did name my module search.module (oops) I'll change that and I'm assuming that'll fix the issue. Thanks for the help, I'm still a noob at custom module creation.

Comment: @Confused: if this answer solved your problem (and it seems so), please mark it as accepted (with clicking the green tick)! Thanks!